# intermittent SSL handshake error nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, handshake

Since a week or so I'm having a SSL problem on my Nginx server intermittently.

I know there are a few other topics on this problem on stackoverflow but none of those answers seem to apply

1 Its a real problem  because when I'm working on the site it just suddenly dies on me and gives me SSL error in Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.155):

> SSL connection error
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

And it happens on FF as well.

2 Server isn't running out of memory (no sign of OOM ran and top all seems ok as well)

3 No updates available for either Nginx (1.8.0) or OpenSSL (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013) running on Debian (7.8)

4 I do not have any special 3rd party libraries installed (just the standard nginx, mariadb, php via fpm setup no email server)

My log has these entries:

> [crit] 15592#15592: *317414 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408A0D7:SSL > routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:required cipher missing) while SSL handshaking,

Server has NTP installed to make sure server time is in sync (right?).

When I experience the problem and give it a few minutes and reload the page it works again but it keeps happening. It doesn't seem to be happening often to other people looking at my logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with:

I had multiple server blocks using the same SSL cert for a few special subdomains and removing that solved the problem completely..

So basically it seems I can only use the CERT in one block (even though its a wildcard cert).. I think the problem is not with the cert but with Nginx accessing the CERT files or something. Using the cert or a regex for multiple subdomains did work (so having only 1 server block with the cert but then defining the domain as *.domain.com)

Comment: So, you added another server block with `server_name *.domain.com` with your SSL configuration, then removed SSL configuration from the other server blocks?

Comment: @AJMaxwell Before I had multiple server blocks for the different subdomains.. I merged them all together using *.domain.com and then just took care of the difference per subdomain in that one server block.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and look into this to solve it.

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,256373